# ASP.NET Web API hide property from EF/LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I have a blog project when C# is the API. I'm using SQL Server 2016. In order to connect to the database I'm using **Entity Framework**.

This is my ADO.NET *.edmx* diagram:

[image]

A user may have many posts, a post may have many authors (Users), a post may have some comments, and a user may have comments.

When I request the API to fetch a user (or a list of users) that's the response: (Endpoint: "/api/users/1")

[image]

I want to hide the password field from the response (I know it's not hashed, but this is for test purposes) so I changed the code from:

[image]

To:

[image]

This is the result using the new code:

[image]

**BUT NOW :(** I see the details of the user **(including passowrd!)** in the posts array!

Is there an efficient way to implement hiding sensitive data from EF/LINQ queries in C# Web API?

Thanks.

Comment: In the Users class, you can set the password to private

Comment: Then I'll able to create/update/delete the password?

Comment: Put the `ScriptIgnore` attribute on the password property, then it won't be serialized to json

Comment: You'll have to use code first for that instead of edmx (edmx is no longer supported in EF so I wouldn't use it anymore if I were you).

Comment: PS. Please post your code, not images. Images can't be copy and also can't be indexed by search engine, like your code will be.

Comment: I still don't get success.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Data Transfer Object. Here the benefits about it. Check the [Create Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5). You can use automap to map automatic.

> Remove circular references (see previous section).
>
> **Hide particular properties that clients are not supposed to view.**
>
> Omit some properties in order to reduce payload size.
>
> Flatten object graphs that contain nested objects, to make them more
>   convenient for clients.
>
> Avoid “over-posting” vulnerabilities. (See Model Validation for a
>   discussion of over-posting.) Decouple your service layer from your
>   database layer.